# AVPlayer Not Playing Videos

Tags: swift, parse-platform, avplayer, parse-server, avplayerviewcontroller

I'm trying to play video from my parse server I'm getting empty video player And when i print the url i get the correct video url

```
let thevideo:PFFile! = (self.selectedmsg["file"] as! PFFile)
            let url:NSURL = NSURL(string: thevideo.url!)!
            let player = AVPlayer(URL: url)

            let playercontroller = AVPlayerViewController()
            playercontroller.player = player

            self.presentViewController(playercontroller, animated: true) {

                player.play()
            }
```

Any help? to play videos from my parse.

Comment: Can you show what output you get for the video url?

Comment: I get a link from my pc like this 127.0.0.1:1337/parse .... mp4